# Want sample code for drawing on finger movement in cocos2d 3.9?

Tags: ios, c++11, cocos2d-x-3.0

how we can achieve this in cocos2d 3.9 with explanation of

> virtual void draw(cocos2d::Renderer *renderer, const cocos2d::Mat4
>   &transform, uint32_t flags) override;

and what is this parameter inside this method?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find good sample in "cpp test" it's provided by default in cocos2d-x folder. Run item with name "RenderTextureTest" in cpp test.

If you want draw finger movement the simplest way it's using `cocos2d::RenderTexture`, this is a Node in which you can draw.
Your code would look like this:

```
void TestScene::onTouchMoved(Touch * touch, Event* event)
{
    Vec2 start = touch->getLocation();
    Vec2 end   = touch->getPreviousLocation();

    // begin drawing to the render texture
    _renderTexture->begin();

    float distance = start.getDistance(end);
    if (distance > 1)
    {
        Sprite * brushSprite = Sprite::create("Images/fire.png");
        brushSprite->setColor(Color3B::RED);
        brushSprite->setOpacity(20);

        for (int i = 0; i < distance; i++)
        {
            float difx = end.x - start.x;
            float dify = end.y - start.y;
            float delta = (float)i / distance;
            brushSprite->setPosition(start.x + (difx * delta), start.y + (dify * delta));
            brushSprite->visit(); // Draw sprite to render texture
        }
    }

    // finish drawing and return context back to the screen
    _renderTexture->end();
}
```

Sorry for my english

Comment: suppose if have to fill color in some structure by finger movement how can in achieve.

Comment: what kind of structure? Not a square?